# Gradient background doesn't fit on page anymore after showing more dataTable rows

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I am currently creating a website with bootstrap and I am using DataTables. There is a little box where you can select how many rows you want to see:
[image]

Now when I select more then 10 entries the background doesn't stretch along with it:
[image]

The css code I use for the background:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(52,138,199), rgb(116,116,191)) no-repeat;
}
```

How can I make it so the background stretches along with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with `height:auto;`:

```
body, html {
    height: auto;
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(52,138,199), rgb(116,116,191)) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did the following now: 
`min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;` 
So it will automatically fill the page and then if it goes beyond 100% it will scale with it.